# Can I include a short story of implementation?

Tags: discussion, scope

After trying to implement functionality mentioned in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/155882/93301) I've run into deep troubles. I learned a very important aspect of C++ template type deduction, and I think that the knowledge could be useful for others, giving more context as to how much I tested the code and how deep understanding of it I have.

Can I include some short explanations as to how I managed to fix the problems?

Comment: I'd say a short description is nice, anything too much is just noise IMO

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I feel so as well, but the story is very interesting from my point of view, and could be beneficial other people. I might write up a blog post about it and just leave a link in the comments.

Comment: Linking to a blog post in the comments seems the most appropriate way to do this IMO. And you get 100% freedom on the content of that post!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an existing mechanism to deal with "I had this specific problem X and fixed it using Y" in the context of the Stackexchange network:
A self-answered question. Since you're describing implementation trouble, it's unfortunately off-topic here. Instead you should post it to Stack Overflow (IIUC)

Regarding the "deep understanding of the code" you have gained ... it's an interesting "bit of trivia" (please don't take this the wrong way), but usually not relevant to the Code Review question you're asking. As such including it in the question most probably is noise.
It's a different story if you have an extensive test-suite, which you just haven't included in the post or similar "further information" that's relevant when providing a review.

Long story short: well done with powering through on the implementation of said enhancement, feel free to share it as a selfie on SO (and link to it in your CR question). But keep in mind that this site is about reviewing code and not about "how I made X work". We don't care how you got to your code, we just care about the "result" :)

Comment: I'd say that *We don't care how you got to your code, we just care about the "result"* is a bit of an exaggeration... consider for example a question such as [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/54737/31562). We don't want just the code, we also want a description about how it works, and I think that in some cases that could include "how I made X work"